# Proof convergence of series $\sum \limits_{n=1}^\infty n^2 * c^k$ with cauchy root test

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I'm struggling proofing the convergence of the following series with cauchy root test:

$\sum \limits_{n=1}^\infty n^2 * c^n$ with $|c| < 1$.

If I use the normal definition of cauchy root test, it is clear: 
$\lim_{n \to \infty} (\sqrt[n]{n^2 * |c|^n}) = \lim_{n \to \infty} (\sqrt[n]{n^2} * |c|) = \lim_{n \to \infty} (\sqrt[n]{n^2}) * \lim_{n \to \infty} (|c|) = 1 * |c| < 1$.

But I would like to use the alternative definition which says that the series converge if $\sqrt[n]{|n^2 * c^n|} < 1$ for all n $\geq n_0$. 
$\sqrt[n]{n^2 * |c|^n} = \sqrt[n]{n^2} * |c|$. But how can I proof that $\sqrt[n]{n^2} * |c|$ < 1? I tested some values and I guess that $\sqrt[n]{n^2}$ is not lower than 1 for all $n \geq n_0$ which will be a problem.

I would be very happy if someone could give me a tip, how to proof it correctly with the alternative definition.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since
$$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to  + \infty } \sqrt[n]{{n^2 }} = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to  + \infty } e^{\frac{2}{n}\log n}  = 1^ +  
$$
you have that
$$
\forall \varepsilon  > 0\,\exists n\left( \varepsilon  \right):\forall n > n\left( \varepsilon  \right) \Rightarrow 1 < \sqrt[n]{{n^2 }} < 1 + \varepsilon 
$$
Now, if
$$
0 < \varepsilon  < \frac{{1 - \left| c \right|}}{{\left| c \right|}}
$$
you get that
$$
\sqrt[n]{{n^2 }}\left| c \right| < \left| c \right|\left( {1 + \varepsilon } \right) < 1
$$
which is true for every $n > n(\varepsilon)$. This is what yo want.